# Python trouble with returning value of a variable

Tags: python, function, python-3.x, return

When I run the first function it prints the correct URL. However, when I run the second section it shows an error saying that fullurl is not defined.

Can anyone help me with this?

Here is my code:

```
def urlmaker(format_mtg):
    fullurl = url + format_mtg.get() + "-constructed-league-" + date.get() #adds the users options to the url
    print(fullurl)
    return fullurl

def htmltotxt(fullurl):
    print(fullurl)
    response = urllib.request.urlopen(fullurl) #requests the ability to open the website, which magic.wizards.com allows
    html = response.read() #reads the html data from the open website
    html = str(html) #saves the data as a string
    make_lists(card_name_regex, card_number_regex, card_number_list, html)
```

Comment: Please use spaces. Python does not charge per character.

Comment: Also, show the actual full error and traceback. Nothing in the code you have posted would give that error.

Comment: You haven't shown how you call these functions. Please include that too. Also, please check your indentation.

Answer (score 1):

Your code without comments and with proper indentation and spacing:

```
def urlmaker(format_mtg):
    fullurl = url + format_mtg.get() + "-constructed-league-" + date.get()
    print(fullurl)
    return fullurl

def htmltotxt(fullurl):
    print(fullurl)
    response = urllib.request.urlopen(fullurl)
    html = response.read()
    html = str(html)
    make_lists(card_name_regex, card_number_regex, card_number_list, html)
```

1. Paste the necessary imports (the ones that are used in the shown code), at least `urllib` should be imported.
2. You are using 5 variables that we don't know: `url`, `date`, `card_name_regex`, `card_number_regex`, `card_number_list`. `date` may not even be a variable but something imported. Define their values or give an example value so that we can reproduce your errors.
3. You are not showing how you call your functions, so we don't know the values of the `format_mtg` and  `fullurl` arguments. I can deduce that you are using the result from the first function as an argument for the second but still measing `format_mtg`.
4. Paste the exception you are getting so that we can help you.

Without those 4 things, we can't find your problem.